# can i use Arrayformula in sumproduct google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, sumproduct

I'm trying to sum the product of three arrays.
All three have the same size (10 rows, 1 col).
The middle array is a text, and I want to lookup the value corresponding to the text in another named table.
So I tried the following formulas:

```
=arrayformula(SUMPRODUCT(K12:K21,vlookup(id_tip_art,'Copy of 002F_OF'!def_manop,3,false),R12:R21))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(K12:K21,arrayformula(vlookup(id_tip_art,'Copy of 002F_OF'!def_manop,3,false)),
R12:R21)
```

#parse ERROR.

Any ideas?
Thx

Following formula works and returns the expected array size, but cannot insert it in sumproduct:

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(id_tip_art,'Copy of 002F_OF'!def_manop,3,false))
```

Comment: Are you sure about  "*" if is a correct syntax? ....3,false)),*R12:R21)...

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: thx mohagali.. syntax issue